# How to give dynamic xpaths to fetch data from xml using Groovy XmlParser?

Tags: groovy

I have this xml where I need to fetch the CPU information, but the tag `CPU"1"` the numeric part might change. how can I give a xpath so that it pics up the numeric part dynamically like till `n`?

My Xml content

```
<CLIENT>
<SYSTEM>
<CPU1 NUMBER="2" SPEED="2300 MHz" Vendor="Advanced Micro Devices" BRAND="AMD Opteron(tm) Processor 6134"></CPU1>
<CPU2 NUMBER="3" SPEED="2300 MHz" Vendor="Advanced Micro Devices" BRAND="AMD Opteron(tm) Processor 6134"></CPU2>
</SYSTEM>
</CLIENT>
```

Currently i get something like below xml generated from the code given

```
<client>
<system>
<cpuinfo>
  <cpu Name="AMD Opteron(tm) Processor 6134" L2CacheSize="NA" MaxClockSpeed="2300 MHz" LoadPercentage="NA"/>
</cpuinfo>  
</system>
</client>
```

My Code

```
@XStreamAlias("cpu")
class cpu{
    @XStreamAsAttribute
    String Name
    @XStreamAsAttribute
    String L2CacheSize
    @XStreamAsAttribute
    String MaxClockSpeed
    @XStreamAsAttribute
    String LoadPercentage

    public cpu(String name, String l2CacheSize, String maxClockSpeed,String loadPercentage) {
        super();
        Name = name;
        L2CacheSize = l2CacheSize;
        MaxClockSpeed = maxClockSpeed;
        LoadPercentage = loadPercentage;
    }

}


@XStreamAlias("system")
public class WindowsSystem extends CSMSystem{
    List<cpu> cpuinfo   

    public WindowsSystem(CSMConfig config, String fileContent){
        super(config)

        cpuinfo = new ArrayList<cpu>()
        WindowsHelper wh=new WindowsHelper(fileContent)
        cpuinfo=wh.getCpuInfo(cpuinfo)
    }   
}


class WindowsHelper {
    private def root
    private List<cpu> cpuinfo

    WindowsHelper(String fileContents)
    {
        root=new XmlParser(false,false).parseText(fileContents)
    }   
    def getCpuInfo(List<cpu> cpuinfo)
    {
        try{
            def cpusize="${root.SYSTEM.CPU1.size()}"
            if(cpusize>0){
                root.SYSTEM.CPU1.each{
                    cpuinfo.add(new cpu(it.@BRAND,"NA",it.@SPEED,"NA"))
                }
                return cpuinfo
            }
            else{
                cpuinfo.add(new cpu("NA","NA","NA","NA"))
                return cpuinfo
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            println "getCpuInfo "+e
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should rewrite getCpuInfo() method of the WindowsHelper class in a such way:

```
def getCpuInfo(List<cpu> cpuinfo)
{
    try {
        def cpusize=root.SYSTEM[0].children().size()            
        if (cpusize > 0) {
            root.SYSTEM[0].children().each { node ->
                if (node.name() ==~ /(?i)cpu\d+/) {
                    cpuinfo.add(new cpu(node.@BRAND, "NA", node.@SPEED, "NA"))
                }
            }
        } 

        if (!cpuinfo) {
            cpuinfo.add(new cpu("NA","NA","NA","NA"))                
        }

        return cpuinfo

    } catch(Exception e) {
        println "getCpuInfo "+e
    }
}
```

Comment: The `SYSTEM` tag will have other children tags too, I think in that case `cpusize=root.SYSTEM.size()` will fail